# Unable to encrypt and decrypt using the Generalized-Feistel Cipher from Black & Rogaway paper

Tags: feistel-network

I am trying to implement the algorithm suggested in Section 5 of the [Black & Rogaway paper titled "Ciphers with Arbitrary Finite Domains"](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/subset.pdf) in C++. It is a Feistel cipher that tries to encipher to a target "unusual" domain size $k$, using cycle-walking when necessary.  This excerpt describes an example:

> In order to specify some particular $\text{Fe}[r, a, b]_K(\cdot)$ we must specify the numbers $a$ and $b$, the number of Feistel rounds $r$, and the choice of underlying functions $F_1,\dots,F_r$ we will use.
>
> As a concrete example, let's take $k=2^{35}, r=3,$ and $a=185360$ and $b=185368$ (methods for finding $a$ and $b$ will be discussed later). Note that $ab \geq k$ as required. Since $ab$ is $74112$ larger than $k$, our Feistel construction will be on the set $M'=[0, (2^{35}-1)+74112]$, meaning there are $74112$ values which are in $M-M'$ for which we will have to iterate (just as we did for the Cycle-walking Cipher). Let's use DES with independent keys as our underlying PRFs. DES is a 64-bit cipher which uses a 56-bit key; we will regard the 64-bit strings on which DES operates as integers in the range $[0, 2^{64}-1]$ in the natural way. We need three PRFs so our key $K = K_1 || K_2 || K_3$ will be $3 \times 56=168$ bits. Now to compute $\text{Fe}[3, 185360, 185368](m)$ we compute $L = m \text{ mod } 185360$, and $R=\lfloor m/185360 \rfloor$ and then perform three rounds of Feistel using $DES_{K_1}(\cdot)$, $DES_{K_2}(\cdot)$, and $DES_{K_3}(\cdot)$ as our underlying PRFs. The first round results in $L\leftarrow \lfloor m/185360 \rfloor$ and $R \leftarrow (m \text{ mod } 185360+DES_{K_1}(\lfloor m/185360 \rfloor))\text{ mod } 185360$, and so on.

This is my attempt at implementation:

```
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

// simple reversible function for now
uint64_t feistelFunction(uint64_t i, uint64_t key)
{
    return i ^ key;
}

uint64_t feistelEncipher(uint64_t m, uint64_t key, uint64_t k)
{
    uint64_t a = std::ceil(std::sqrt(k)); // a == b to test
    uint64_t b = std::ceil(std::sqrt(k));

    uint64_t L = m % a;
    uint64_t R = m / a;

    // round 1
    uint64_t tmp = (L + feistelFunction(R, key)) % a;
    L = R;
    R = tmp;

    // round 2
    tmp = (L + feistelFunction(R, key)) % b;
    L = R;
    R = tmp;

    // round 3
    tmp = (L + feistelFunction(R, key)) % a;
    L = R;
    R = tmp;

    return (a*L) + R;
}

uint64_t feistelDecipher(uint64_t m, uint64_t key, uint64_t k)
{
    uint64_t a = std::ceil(std::sqrt(k)); // a == b to test
    uint64_t b = std::ceil(std::sqrt(k));

    uint64_t L = m / a;
    uint64_t R = m % a;

    // round 1
    uint64_t tmp = (R - feistelFunction(L, key)) % a;
    R = L;
    L = tmp;

    // round 2
    tmp = (R - feistelFunction(L, key)) % b;
    R = L;
    L = tmp;

    // round 3
    tmp = (R - feistelFunction(L, key)) % a;
    R = L;
    L = tmp;

    return (a*R) + L;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t k = 100; // k is [1, 100]

    std::mt19937 g((std::random_device()())); // seeded with a random_device call
    auto rand = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, k);
    uint64_t key = rand(g); // test with all same keys

    uint64_t test;
    std::cout << "testing with 10" << std::endl;
    test = feistelEncipher(10, key, 100);
    std::cout << "enciphered to " << test << std::endl;
    test = feistelDecipher(test, key, 100);
    std::cout << "deciphered to " << test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and one test run returns:

```
% ./a.out
testing with 10
enciphered to 85
deciphered to 12
```

So I have something wrong. What is wrong with my implementation? I have only seen Feistel networks that use exclusive or with the output of $F(R)$. Is summing and taking the modulus just as reversible?